# Error while trying to install OKD 3.11 in air-gapped or disconnected environment (RHEL 7.4)

Tags: openshift, okd

As part of a OKD 3.11 setup on on-premise virtual servers running on RHEL-7.4,
facing below error there. Necessary rpm packages were installed as part of installation (Ex: Ansible Playbooks).
The OKD 3.11 installation files were retrieved from Github repository here at
https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/tree/release-3.11

```
fatal: [dstoicpwkl01v]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "allow_downgrade": false, 
            "autoremove": false, 
            "bugfix": false, 
            "conf_file": null, 
            "disable_excludes": null, 
            "disable_gpg_check": false, 
            "disable_plugin": [], 
            "disablerepo": [], 
            "download_dir": null, 
            "download_only": false, 
            "enable_plugin": [], 
            "enablerepo": [], 
            "exclude": [], 
            "install_repoquery": true, 
            "install_weak_deps": true, 
            "installroot": "/", 
            "list": null, 
            "lock_timeout": 30, 
            "name": [
                "https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm"
            ], 
            "releasever": null, 
            "security": false, 
            "skip_broken": false, 
            "state": "present", 
            "update_cache": false, 
            "update_only": false, 
            "use_backend": "auto", 
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to dl.fedoraproject.org at port 443: [Errno -2] Name or service not known", 
    "status": -1, 
    "url": "https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
dstoicpmal02v              : ok=19   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=40   rescued=0    ignored=0   
dstoicpwkl01v              : ok=14   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=32   rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=11   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=5    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Any inputs to overcome this dependency, appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should install epel before deploying OKD 3.11:

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
```

May be you are behind a firewall, and are not able to reach the site https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm